# What are these insects in my potted Schlumbergera?

Tags: identification, soil, insects, cactus

I have little insects in pot with [Schlumbergera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlumbergera). They are crawling in soil, and occasionally on the pot (it's yellow plastic). I don't see them on plant itself.

They are not really in big numbers or disturbing in any way and plant is OK.
I'm just curious, but maybe I should get rid of them. They are not jumping when I poke them, just crawling.

I'm not sure if they are insects or bugs or mites or whatever mites.

[image: insect in question]

Update:
I think it's [Hypoaspis miles](https://goo.gl/images/EUy4iK). I am having fungus gnats for some time and also Springtails. And this bugs appeared. At first I was like "Another pest..." and blamed bad soil from shop, but... this is actually solution for my other insect problems! I'll observe general situation about all this and decide what to do.

But hey, they are still crawling... bugs... kind of scary, I just want flowers, not bugs :)

Comment: Just in the soil?  How many legs can you count?  Six or eight?  Not really sure of the scale...but with the texture of the paper...are you using a micro lens or that function on a digital?  Look under the leaves and intersections more closely.  Using a Loupe?  I LOVE the microworld.  There are these inexpensive specimen microscopes with a LIGHT...about 14-15 dollars?  You have to get one for this kind of investigation!  What prompted you to LOOK and SEE these guys?

Comment: I used digital camera and Magnifying glass.

Comment: The image is just a little piece of photo. I was like "what are this bugs in my flowers?" and couldn't find answer... Microworld can be scary sometimes.

Comment: Yup, I think I sent this picture to you.  If I didn't and both of us came to the same conclusion, same picture then we might be on the right path?  Are these guys IN YOUR FLOWERS or just the soil?  Let's find out what they truly are.  One skill to become successful with plants is understanding insects.  Most insects as far as humans are concerned are good guys, not only necessary but critical in our environment.  All insects have a place in the ecosystem, we are the only life forms that do not.  If I could do this all over again I would become an entomologist, seriously!

Comment: I'm pretty sure my mites are good ones. Everything about them is like what I'm read in different sources: they are just in soil and on pot, mostly visible at night and fungus gnats are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Soil mites](https://goo.gl/images/EUy4iK)

If you can count 8 legs and you find no signs of spider mite on your plant then this guy is a Soil Mite, and lucky you!!  This is a delightful predator!  Do not! use any pesticide or try to eradicate them.  They are the good guys.

Comment: Not really correct answer, but I looked into good insects and found out about Hypoaspis miles, see my update